# Getting different Date time locally and remotely

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I am using `ZonedDateTime` to convert `GMT` timestamp to `America/Phoenix` timestamp,

Here is my implementation

```
 public static ZonedDateTime convertGMTTimestampToLocalTime(Timestamp gmtTime, String timeZone) throws Exception
    {

        ZonedDateTime atZone =Instant
                .ofEpochMilli(                       // Parse a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z.
                        gmtTime.getTime()
                )                                    // Returns a `Instant` object.
                .atZone(                            
                        ZoneId.of( timeZone )
                );                                    // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.


        return atZone;
    }
```

This gives proper result when I test in local but when I test it remotely (`server` with `docker container`) it gives wrong result.

If I do a transaction at `6-Jan-2021 8:00PM (America/Phoenix)` it should give 6-Jan-2021 instead it display 7-Jan-2021. My server is in `MST`

What am I missing, isn't the server supposed to print the date according to the specified time zone. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the docker container is using MST? It may not use the same timezone as the server...

Comment: I checked the server timezone it was MST not dockers

Comment: Just to be clear - you entered the docker container and checked that it used MST? If not, try.

Comment: yes, you are correct, its using MST timezone @ewramner

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use the terrible legacy classes `Timestamp`, `Date`, `Calendar`, etc. These were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## Use *java.time*

If handed an object of that class, immediately convert to `Instant`. The `Instant` class represents a moment as seen in in UTC, with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = myTimestamp.toInstant() ;
```

Adjust to your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Phoenix" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Generate text representing the value of that `LocalDate` object.

```
String iso8601 = ld.toString() ;
```

Or automatically localize.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).
String localized = ld.format( f ) ;
```

You said:

> My server is in MST

First, servers should generally be kept to a default time zone of UTC, that is no zone, just an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Secondly, as a Java programmer, write your code without depending on the default time zone. Specify explicitly the desired time zone by passing the otherwise optional time zone argument to the various date-time methods.

Thirdly, `MST` is not a real time zone.